# Free Batch Photo Watermaker?

Tags: photo-editing, batch, watermark

I want to place a small logo in the bottom of about 100 images at onces.

Is there a cool, free and easy program I can download where I can do this?

I basically want to place a signature watermark in all of the 100 images in 1 location.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: On what operating system? ImageMagick or GIMP come to mind, but I'm not sure they they fit the "easy" bill, since they do so much more than that... (*ponder*)

Comment: If it is a text, Irfanview (batch mode, advanced options).

Comment: Windows 7...........yeah i need to do them in bulk and I dont think GIMP allow that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [FastStone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm):

1. Once you open the viewer (if you opened it in a single picture view - press **ENTER** to open Manager), you can select any number of pictures you want
2. Then follow the menu **Tools** / **Batch Convert Selected Images** (or just press F3)
3. Click **Advanced Options** button
4. Open **Watermark** tab, and place a flag on **Add Watermark** checkbox
5. Adjust it as you want and click OK
6. In that window you can specify some other settings also
7. Press **Convert**

Answer (score 4):

[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) is probably the most popular program that can also do that. It has a simple GUI interface. [Here is the Google help page on how to use it](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106193).

You can also use [NConvert](http://www.xnview.com) with you own script or have [XnView](http://www.xnview.com) generate a batch file that will call NConvert for you. NConvert is command line, so you need to do the calculations for exact positioning (how many pixels to from edges).

Comment: I actually want to place a image in as a watermark.....